# For each unique user id create a vector of histogram frequencies R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, cluster-analysis

I have 608 unique user ids with total of ~58,000 events.

```
User.ID      state of charge
1000749          47.08
998235V          93.00
...              ...
```

I am trying to create a vector of each id which includes their histogram$counts

```
<Input> {r for each user id create a vector }
list.ids=list()
#stchrg=SOCData$SOC
for (i in unique(SOCData$User.ID)){
  list.ids[[i]]=(hist(SOCData$SOC)$counts/sum(hist(SOCData$SOC)$count))*100
}
View(list.ids)
length(list.ids)
#the length is right it returns 608 which is correct
```

```
<Output>
list of each id=c(frequencies for 10 breaks)
```

For now, I get the same frequency values for all the ids which needs to be adjusted and Idk how!

Later, I want to either put all the arrays together to calculate the distances or have them all in one matrix. If you recommend any better approach for having such final result, I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heads up! May bins end up not being uniform and equal for various users so I defined my bin and later implemented in my hist()

```
bins=c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
list.ids = list()
for (i in unique(SOCData$User.ID)) {
list.ids[[as.character(i)]] =as.vector(hist(SOCData[SOCData$User.ID == i, 'SOC'], breaks=bins)$counts / sum(hist(SOCData[SOCData$User.ID == i, 'SOC'], breaks =bins)$count) * 100)
}
```